# Does logstash downloads logs from s3 or it reads without downloading?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logstash

I'm using logstash to process logs to our centralized logging and the inputs are at s3 in gz format. I need to create a cost projection regarding this process and does logstash download the s3 object or it parse it remotely?

Comment: Where is logstash running?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein I have it running as a service at my ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon S3 is an object storage service. Data is not "processed" on Amazon S3.

If an application wants to process data from Amazon S3, it would need to download the files from Amazon S3 and process the data locally. An exception to this is if the application uses the [Amazon S3 Select](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/) service, which can query data directly on Amazon S3.

In terms of **cost**, if the Amazon EC2 instance is in the same region as the Amazon S3 bucket, there is no data transfer cost for downloading the data.

Comment: Hi , my bucket and my instance are both located at us-west-2. So it means that my logstash-s3 process won't cost a thing?

Comment: There will be no **Data Transfer** cost. There is an API cost for retrieving from Amazon S3 ($0.0004 per 1,000 requests), but that's going to be small.

Comment: Thank you @John! How about the backup_to_dir function by logstash ?  i think it's a cut and paste method. :o

Comment: Sorry, but I am not familiar enough with logstash to be able to comment on that.